# Rendering app/doc files from within an app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I render specific rdoc files (in this case, Readme.rdoc) in my 'app/doc' folder within the parent Rails app (from which the rdoc files have been generated)? I'd like to render this page, along with the rdoc .css files to nicely format the output, but also stay within my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

Generate a new controller (Rdocs for example)

```
rails g controller Rdocs index
```

Add this in routes

```
get "rdocs/index"
match "rdocs", :to => "rdocs#index"
```

Your controller

```
def index
  render :text => File.open(Rails.root + "doc/README_FOR_APP", 'r').read       
end
```

OR if your using markdown

```
def index
  m = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML)
  content = m.render(File.open(Rails.root + "doc/README_FOR_APP", 'r').read)
  render :text => content
end
```

Then call `/rdocs`

Comment: Great solution. I was trying to achieve exactly that, but was having trouble distilling it down to only a modest amount of code, just like you did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative: I wanted to display the README.rdoc on an /about page.

In controller:

```
@readme = RDoc::Markup::ToHtml.new.convert(File.open(Rails.root.join('README.rdoc'), 'r').read)
```

In view:

```
<div class="readme">
  <h4>README.rdoc</h4>
  <div class="rdoc">
    <%= @readme.html_safe %>
  </div>
</div>
```